# MySQL Remote Connection Refused (111)

Tags: networking, server, mysql

I am getting a 111 error when attempting to connect. I have tried every which way I can find, all the various tutorials and fix attempts. I discovered, however, that via a remote server, I am able to connect to the other mysql database server via telnet, including the password, user and database. I am wondering if anyone has some light they can shed on this, because I'm at a loss.